# When I use ie.navigate twice, the document remains the same

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I have the next code (tried different variations, this is the newest):

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "URL1"
Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

ie.document.getElementById("_58_login").Value = login
ie.document.getElementById("_58_password").Value = password
ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary")(0).Click


ie.navigate "URL2"
Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Set elements = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("title")
MsgBox elements(0).innerText
```

Basically, it navigates to a login page first, logs in, then navigates to the desired page with the info I want to scrape. And the browser does navigate to the second page correctly. However, although the second page is loaded and can be interacted with, it seems like "ie.document" still contains the login page (msgbox displays the title of the login page and I cannot GetElementsByTagName that should be present on the second page).

I have tried using DoEvents loop everywhere. Also, I have tried to use Application.wait but it results in error (application method "wait" failed 1004).

So I expect:
1. Navigate to login page and log in (click the button).
2. Navigate to another page, click some buttons (the web-site is heavily scripted and uses scripted buttons to navigate further) and finally fetch a table with data.

Comment: I try to test the above code and find that after moving to second page it is able to find the control on the second page on my side. I suggest you to try to make a test with just above code can work on your side and possible that some other code causing the issue.

Comment: As for me, this code cannot find elements on the second page (all elements remain from the first page). I can only guess that this might be happening due to the web-site structure. Strictly speaking, it does not have any links - all navigation is done via java-script: all links are actually buttons that just send some information and retrive new. Unfortunately, I cannnot share the link (it is classified)

Comment: Maybe more time is needed to load the second document.  Try waiting a bit before trying to get your elements, maybe start with about a 10 second pause/delay, and see if that helps.